# From an application running in remote desktop, how to programmatically get a file that has been copied to the client clipboard and save it to disk

Tags: .net, vb6, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, file-copying

This is the scenario:

1. User opens a remote desktop session on a server running Windows 2008 Server R2.
2. The remote desktop session does not use mapped drives but clipboard sharing is enabled.
3. User launches MyApplication in the remote desktop session.
4. User opens Windows Explorer on client machine and copies a file to the clipboard.
5. In MyApplication (in the remote desktop session) user clicks a "Save File" button.
6. MyApplication gets the file from the clipboard and saves it to some directory on the server.

MyApplication is an old vb6 application, but it is okay to implement this in .Net and use it through com interop. We have tried both the Clipboard class in vb6 and the Systems.Windows.Forms.Clipboard class in .Net. 
In either case the only thing that seems to be on the clipboard is the file path on the client machine. This is of no use since the code is running on the server and we need to get the file from the server.

We have also confirmed that this does work when we manually paste the file into Windows Explorer on the server (through remote desktop).
We did find some examples that show how to do this by running another program on the client, but that is not an option for us. This has to work over just remote  desktop.
Any help, code samples, links to documentation etc. would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So drive sharing over the remote desktop connection is **not** enabled?  (When you go to Options, Local Resources and click More the "Drives" option is unticked)

If so then copying and pasting a file over a remote desktop connection to a Windows Exporer window doesn't work, and I can't see how it would - file clipboard / drag and drop operations essentially work by placing the file path on the clipboard, and then allowing the destination application do what they wish with the file (normally copy the file or open it).  When using drive sharing over remote desktop the files are available through the `//tsclient` "share", however unless this is enabled on the remote connection the destination application (including Windows Explorer) will have no way of accessing the file.

If drive sharing is enabled then you should find that the path to the file (as accessible through the `//tsclient` share) is placed in the clipboard - you should be able to access files under this path in a similar way to files on any other share.

You may also find a clipboard viewer (like [this one](http://www.peterbuettner.de/develop/tools/clipview/index.html)) useful.

Comment: Yes, drive sharing is **not** enabled. And it is still possible to manually copy a file from the client and paste it inside the remote desktop session. Apparently this has been supported from RDP 6.0 onwards. I will try to see if I can find documentation somewhere. This KB article indirectly mentions it: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2258090

Comment: @Ashish In that case I'm not sure how it would work - my guess is that the entire file contents is placed in the clipboard.  Have you tried that clipboard viewer?

Comment: No I haven't tried the clipboard viewer yet, but will do so today. Will let you know what I find.

Comment: Tried it. When I copy a file, under Format it shows: DataObject, FileGroupDescriptorW, FileContents, Preferred DropEffect and Ole Private Data. DataObject shows some weird characters in the Content box. All others are blank. Copying text instead of a file does show the expected text in the content box.